# How to force Game Center submit score failure

Tags: unity, ios, game-center

What would cause a failure to report a score to a Game Center leaderboard?
Currently, score reporting succeeds almost all the time, so I'm trying to force failure so I can fix it.

The Game Center documentation says it would fail to report a score if there are network issues.  Are there any other scenarios where reporting a score would fail?

I'm using Prime31's Game Center plugin for Unity3D.

Comment: The **reason** that scores fail to send is likely less important than you think it is.